# Repeat request to another php-fpm script via fastcgi?

Tags: nginx, http

I have nginx server accepting incoming HTTP requests and serving it via fastcgi to some php-fpm script (for example index.php). I want nginx to repeat the same request to another php-fpm script via fastcgi (for example noresponse.php). I don't even need to get answer from this script, just make a request. As I don't need to get asnwer, maybe it is even possible to make UDP request and pass $_SERVER variables (using lua, for example)?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply include the noresponse.php at the end of index.php.

Comment: Pretty easy, but I want this scripts to be executed approximately simultaneously.